# How to create L Shape div in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

i have two divs
DIV 1 & DIV 2
how to create them so that Div1 comes as L Shape like this

[HERE IS IMAGE SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efM8O.png)

here as the shape changes the content is adjusting as per increased width
i could not get a clue of how to even start with this ?
div2 content will in left out shape

Comment: You can't. All html elements are rectangular.

Comment: That said you can float the small div INSIDE the larger one and the content will flow around it.

Comment: when i am doing that , Div 2 is coming down of Div 1 not side by side

Comment: Div 2 must be inside div 1, and div 2 will need to come before the other content in div 1 to float in the top right corner.

Comment: in that case div 1  content is down  once div 2 content is finished so there is blank space in div 1 and when div 2 height finishes div 2 content start loading

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try with this

```
     <div   Style="height:300px">
  <div style="width:'30%';height:"100px";float: 'right'; marginBottom: '15px'; marginLeft: '15px' ">

  RIGHT SIDE DIV CONTENT 
  </div>
  PARENT L SHPAED DIV CONTENT 

</div>
```